# How to return list in SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

code below return me list of two objects like this:

```
[
    {
        value: "ssss",
    },
    {
        value: "ssss",
    },
]
```

but i want to return list like this:

```
{
    value1:"xxxx",
    value2:"xxxx"
}
```

here is my code

```
    @Override
    public List<OrderModel> getOrderByCode(UserEntity user) throws ErrorException {

        List<UserEntity> userOrder = userRepository.findByUserAndOrderCodeIn(user, Arrays.asList(OrderCodes.OK, OrderCodes.DONE));

        List<OrderModel> om = new ArrayList<OrderModel>();
        for(UserAnswerEntity userAnswerEntity : userAnswers){
            OrderModel orderModel = new OrderModel();
            orderModel.setValue(userAnswerEntity.getValue());

            om.add(orderModel );
        }

        return om;
    }
```

```
public class OrderModel{

    String value;

//get,set
}
```

can someon tell me how can i return only list like above?

Comment: is this json that you are expecting is in valid format

Comment: thanks, I accidentally entered the wrong json, could you look and improve your example?

Comment: according to the updated json it is a Map<String,String> not a list. Try with a Map, you can get idea with @rahulP answer by ignoring last line

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to make a custom response. One of the possible way is this

```
Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
map.put("key1", "value1");
map.put("key2", "value2");

System.out.println(map.toString().replace("{", "[").replace("}", "]"));
```

Comment: thanks, I accidentally entered the wrong json, could you look and improve your example?

Comment: You can directly return map then you won't need to do any conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Change the return type of getOrderByCode() to string and convert your List object to JSON string.

```
private static final ObjectMapper jsonMapper = new ObjectMapper().setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);
return jsonMapper.writeValueAsString(om);
```

Comment: thanks, I accidentally entered the wrong json, could you look and improve your example?

Comment: @Escanor16 I would suggest you, parse your JSON string using JSONObject and make your custom format using stringBuilder.

Answer (score 0):

for you example, you can use `Map` instead of `List`

try this:

```
  AtomicInteger index = new AtomicInteger()
  Function<UserAnswerEntity, String> createIndex = (userAnswer) -> "value" + index.getAndIncrement();
  return userAnswers.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(createIndex, UserAnswerEntity::getValue));
```